# If Then Statement & Equal To Reference Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

I am having a slight problem, and I think someone (obviously smarter than me) can help guide me.  For some reason I can't get this to work correctly:

& me.prepayment_month = ""

Prepayment_Month is a dropdown list of all the months.  If I enter a month, and step through the code, the month is recognized.  My problem is when it's blank.  It is not recognizing this condition. I have tried Null, "", Blank, and all not recognized.

```
Private Sub Add_Prepayment_Save()
DoCmd.Save acForm, "frmInvoices"
If Me.Rec_d_Prepayment = 0 Then
DoCmd.Save acForm, "frmInvoices"
End If
If Me.Rec_d_Prepayment <> 0 & Me.prepayment_month = " " Then
    MsgBox "Please Update Prepayment Month"
End If
If Me.Rec_d_Prepayment <> 0 & Me.prepayment_month <> "" Then
    MsgBox "This will be added to tblPrePayment"
End If
End Sub
```

------- Update 1 ---------

```
Private Sub Add_Prepayment_Save()
DoCmd.Save acForm, "frmInvoices"
If Me.Rec_d_Prepayment = 0 Then
DoCmd.Save acForm, "frmInvoices"
End If
If Me.Rec_d_Prepayment <> 0 And Me.prepayment_month = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Update Prepayment Month"
End If
If Me.Rec_d_Prepayment <> 0 And Me.prepayment_month <> "" Then
    MsgBox "This will be added to tblPrePayment"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i wouldnt say smarter, perhaps simply more experienced. my brain is flawed as well, that is why i can relate to this error. the & operator in VBA is for concatenating strings.  i am surprised this even got passed the compiler. try using .... AND

Comment: @semisided1 I have used "AND" and it still is not recognizing. I have updated the code to include my most recent updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand concatenates strings together in VB based languages. To implement a logical `AND` operator, use the `AND` keyword. What you're doing is gluing a zero to the value of `Me.prepayment_month`.

Comment: I have used "AND" and it still is not recognizing. I have updated the code to include my most recent updates.

Comment: @bjk if you type `MsgBox Me.prepayment_month` what does it say?

Comment: @user278524 If the cell is empty -Run time error '94':  Invalid use of Null.  If the cell has a value, it is showing the value.  Not sure if it matters but the Row Source Type is "Value List".  The formatting in the cell property is blank, with no available options in the drop down.

Comment: @user278524 I just tried the code below, and I got the message box.  Does this make sense or a seem like a viable option in the context of my full updated code above?

If IsNull(Prepayment_Month) Then MsgBox "this worked!"

Comment: @bjk That seems right, I would have thought you could get by with trying to compare to an empty string which is essentially no data, whereas `null` is a value assigned. I'm guessing the dropdown list assigns `null` when it's empty rather than having an absence data.